# Map of Map iteration

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Im storing 2 map with different structure in single map like below,

```
Map<String, List<String>> colMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
Map<String, String> appMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
// colMap assigning some values
// appMap assigning some values
Map<String, Map> mainMap = new HashMap<String, Map>();
mainMap.put("appMap", appMap);
mainMap.put("colMap", colMap);
```

I want to get map one by one and iterate the map.

If I try get map like below, getting error,

```
  .......
  Map colMap = map.get("colMap");
  for(Entry<String, List<String>> entry : colMap.entrySet())

Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Map.Entry<String,List<String>>
```

Comment: This is why mixing types, especially generic types, is usually not a good idea. If you must go with this design, you'll need to cast it on the way out. Also you should never use raw types.

Comment: @shmosel everything you've said is right, but would you like to point out where a raw type has been used here ?

Comment: Just curious, maybe you caught something I may have missed.

Comment: @was1209 I think shmosel was referring to `Map<String, Map> mainMap = new HashMap<String, Map>();`

Comment: Ah...Hadn't caught that Map, gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a simple container POJO class (or record in Java 16+) for the two maps instead of `mainMap` and keep the relevant type-safety which to do it Java-way?

```java
public class MapPojo {
    private final Map<String, List<String>> colMap;
    private final Map<String, String> appMap;

    public MapPojo(Map<String, List<String>> colMap, Map<String, String> appMap) {
        this.colMap = colMap;
        this.appMap = appMap;
    }
    // getters, etc.
}

MapPojo mainMap = new MapPojo(colMap, appMap);
```

Comment: Or just keep the 2 variables and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

Error you are getting because when you are doing map.get operation your reference is Just Map without any Generics which will treated as Object class's reference. You should use generics like below and it will work -

```
Map<String, List<String>> colMap = map.get("colMap");
for(Entry<String, List<String>> entry : colMap.entrySet())
```